# Solve the PDE $u_{tt}+2u_{xx}+3u_{xt}-u_t-2u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve the PDE $u_{tt}+2u_{xx}+3u_{xt}-u_t-2u=0$

By a change of variables where $\beta=2t-x$ and $\alpha =x-t$ I have factorised the equation to $$(\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}-2)(\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}+1)u=0$$
But I am unsure as to how to solve this PDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have factorized your equation, you can assume that the solution is 
$$ u(\alpha, \beta) = f(\alpha) g (\beta).$$

We then find that
$$\left(\frac{d}{d\beta} +1  \right) g(\beta) = 0 \tag{1}$$
or
$$ \left(\frac{d}{d\alpha}-2  \right)f(\alpha) =0 \tag{2}$$
guarantees that $u$ solves the PDE. 
So we have reduced the PDE in the set of ODE's (1) and (2). The solution to the latter reads $$f(\alpha) = C_1 e^{2 \alpha}$$ and the former implies $$g(\beta) = C_2 e^{-\beta}.$$

So in total (using the linearity), we have
$$ u(\alpha,\beta) = C_1(\beta) e^{2 \alpha} + C_2(\alpha) e^{-\beta}$$
with arbitrary functions $C_1, C_2$ as the solution of the PDE.

Answer (score 0):

- $2 {{D}_{x}^{2}}+3 {D_t}\, {D_x}+{{D}_{t}^{2}}-{D_t}-2=\left( {D_x}+{D_t}+1\right) \, \left( 2 {D_x}+{D_t}-2\right) $
- solution of $u_x+u_t+u=0$ is $u_1=e^{-t}f(x-t)$
- solution of $2u_x+u_t-2u=0$ is $u_1=e^{2t}g(x-2t)$
- then $u=u_1+u_2=e^{-t}f(x-t)+e^{2t}g(x-2t)$